# Vue.js2 : How to reuse a constant defined inside a component

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I want to define a const value inside the mounted function. And want to use this const value inside the methods of a vue component.

Example :

```
export default {
    name : 'app',
    data(){

    },
    mounted(){
        // Constant refThis is defined here which gets the reference to this vue component 
        const refThis = this;

    },
    methods:{
        useThisRef() {
            // I want to be able to use the refThis here 
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get a a reference to refThis in other parts of the vue component ?

Comment: It seems that you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/252139), please explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @Nit Thanks for enlightening me about the XY problem. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you need `refThis` when you have `this`?

Comment: I am sorry should have mentioned this in the question, but sometimes it doesn't return the properties, when using this directly. @Bert

Comment: Do you mean in a callback?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to vue.js, I am not sure what exactly qualifies as a callback in this context @Bert

Comment: You said that *sometimes* this doesn't return the properties. That typically only happens if you have defined a callback function incorrectly, as you might inside an API call with something like axios or some other promise handler (the function inside then for example).

Comment: @Bert Indeed it is a callback return data. And yes its implementing a promise handler. How do you propose is the right way to correctly define this. I mean it looks like a type mismatch. And I am guessing, there is no type casting in JS. But it still doesn't explain why it works when we are using something like var refThis = this;

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score -1):

Can you do something like in a `const.js` file:

```
export const ConstName = {
  //Code in here
}
```

Then you can import this in any component at the top:

```
import ConstName form '/path/to/const.js
```

Comment: This is not related to the question at all.